# Two jquery pie charts same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two adjustable jquery pie charts on the same page. I added PieID2 to create the second chart, but the first chart isn't completing the 360 degree circle now. Can anyone assist? I'm not sure what I need to change or add to get multiple pie charts on the same page and have all charts functioning properly.

```js
function sliceSize(dataNum, dataTotal) {
  return (dataNum / dataTotal) * 360;
}

function addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color) {
  $(pieElement).append("<div class='slice " + sliceID + "'><span></span></div>");
  var offset = offset - 1;
  var sizeRotation = -179 + sliceSize;
  $("." + sliceID).css({
    "transform": "rotate(" + offset + "deg) translate3d(0,0,0)"
  });
  $("." + sliceID + " span").css({
    "transform": "rotate(" + sizeRotation + "deg) translate3d(0,0,0)",
    "background-color": color
  });
}

function iterateSlices(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, dataCount, sliceCount, color) {
  var sliceID = "s" + dataCount + "-" + sliceCount;
  var maxSize = 179;
  if (sliceSize <= maxSize) {
    addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
  } else {
    addSlice(maxSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
    iterateSlices(sliceSize - maxSize, pieElement, offset + maxSize, dataCount, sliceCount + 1, color);
  }
}

function createPie(dataElement, pieElement) {
  var listData = [];
  $(dataElement + " span").each(function() {
    listData.push(Number($(this).html()));
  });
  var listTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
    listTotal += listData[i];
  }
  var offset = 0;
  var color = [
    "#182a54",
    "#025971",
    "#ecaa20",
    "#5a622b",
    "#82332e",
    "purple",
    "turquoise",
    "forestgreen",
    "navy",
    "gray"
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
    var size = sliceSize(listData[i], listTotal);
    iterateSlices(size, pieElement, offset, i, 0, color[i]);
    $(dataElement + " li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").css("border-color", color[i]);
    offset += size;
  }
}
createPie(".pieID.legend", ".pieID.pie");
createPie(".pieID2.legend", ".pieID2.pie");
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
@keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  background: #EEE;
}

main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.pieID {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pieID2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pie {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.pie::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 220px auto;
}

.slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  animation: bake-pie 1s;
}

.slice span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}

.legend {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDD, 2px 2px 0 #BBB;
}

.legend li {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1.25em solid black;
}

.legend em {
  font-style: normal;
}

.legend span {
  float: right;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="pieID pie">

  </div>
  <ul class="pieID legend">
    <li>
      <em>Unsheltered</em>
      <span>514</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <em>Sheltered</em>
      <span>410</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="pieID2 pie">

  </div>
  <ul class="pieID2 legend">
    <li>
      <em>Adults (25-60)</em>
      <span>304</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <em>Youth (18-24)</em>
      <span>87</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <em>Seniors</em>
      <span>35</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <em>Children</em>
      <span>4</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <em>Unknown</em>
      <span>81</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from 1st class overrides the data from 1st pie since they both are asigned same slice class in function `addSlice`

To Avoid this you need to modify 2 things in function `addSlice`

- Change `$("."+sliceID).css` to `$(pieElement + " ."+sliceID).css`
- Change `$("."+sliceID+" span").css` to `$(pieElement + " ."+sliceID+" span").css`

```js
function sliceSize(dataNum, dataTotal) {
  return (dataNum / dataTotal) * 360;
}

function addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color) {
  $(pieElement).append("<div class='slice "+sliceID+"'><span></span></div>");
  var offset = offset - 1;
  var sizeRotation = -179 + sliceSize;
  $(pieElement + " ."+sliceID).css({
    "transform": "rotate("+offset+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)"
  });
  $(pieElement + " ."+sliceID+" span").css({
    "transform"       : "rotate("+sizeRotation+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)",
    "background-color": color
  });
}

function iterateSlices(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, dataCount, sliceCount, color) {
  var sliceID = "s"+dataCount+"-"+sliceCount;
  var maxSize = 179;
  if(sliceSize<=maxSize) {
    addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
  } else {
    addSlice(maxSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
    iterateSlices(sliceSize-maxSize, pieElement, offset+maxSize, dataCount, sliceCount+1, color);
  }
}

function createPie(dataElement, pieElement) {
  var listData = [];
  $(dataElement+" span").each(function() {
    listData.push(Number($(this).html()));
  });
  var listTotal = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
    listTotal += listData[i];
  }
  var offset = 0;
  var color = [
    "#182a54", 
    "#025971", 
    "#ecaa20", 
    "#5a622b", 
    "#82332e", 
    "purple", 
    "turquoise", 
    "forestgreen", 
    "navy", 
    "gray"
  ];
  for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
    var size = sliceSize(listData[i], listTotal);
    iterateSlices(size, pieElement, offset, i, 0, color[i]);
    $(dataElement+" li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").css("border-color", color[i]);
    offset += size;
  }
}
createPie(".pieID.legend", ".pieID.pie");
createPie(".pieID2.legend", ".pieID2.pie");
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

@keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  background: #EEE;
}
main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.pieID {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.pieID2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.pie {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.pie::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 220px auto;
  
}
.slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  animation: bake-pie 1s;
}
.slice span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}
.legend {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDD,
              2px 2px 0 #BBB;
}
.legend li {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1.25em solid black;
}
.legend em {
  font-style: normal;
}
.legend span {
  float: right;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="pieID pie"></div>
  <ul class="pieID legend">
    <li><em>Unsheltered</em><span>514</span></li>
    <li><em>Sheltered</em><span>410</span></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="pieID2 pie"></div>
  <ul class="pieID2 legend">
    <li><em>Adults (25-60)</em><span>304</span></li>
    <li><em>Youth (18-24)</em><span>87</span></li>
    <li><em>Seniors</em><span>35</span></li>
    <li><em>Children</em><span>4</span></li>
    <li><em>Unknown</em><span>81</span></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```